# Understanding Intrinsic locks in java for synchronization on different object instances

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I'm understanding synchronization and struck with few doubts after going through different blogs. As per my understanding, Intrinsic lock is acquired by a thread when accessing a synchronized method and other threads need to wait until the first one completes execution giving up the lock for the second thread to execute. But what if both the threads try to access the synchronized blocks from the different object? will that be still called synchronization or not?

```
class A{

      public static synchronized void m1() throws InterruptedException{
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Completed Execution by "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
          }
    
          public static void main(String j[]){
            
              
             new Thread(()->{
                 try{
                   new A().m1();  // New object calling m1()
                 }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
             }).start();
          
             new Thread(()->{
                 try{
                   new A().m1();     // New object calling m1()
                 }catch(InterruptedException ie){}
             }).start();
          
          }
}
```

[![Synchronization when separte objects are invoked][1]][1]

Above output When the synchronization is changed to static like

```
 public static synchronized void m1() throws InterruptedException{  //static method
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Completed Execution by "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }
```

[![Static Synchronization output][2]][2]

Above output When the static is removed only with synchronized left making it appear as not synchronized from the console output.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSKJn.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMx4t.png

So my query is when the method is declared static synchronized and when the different threads calling that method gets the lock from which object ? As when synchronized method is called from different new instances of object need not be called synchronized and the lock is attained on which object in this case?

Comment: When the method is static, they lock on the `Class` object, i.e. `A.class`.

Comment: `But what if both the threads try to access the synchronized blocks from the different object?` You actually have several questions here.  You should break the question up into more than one question.  For different objects, they use *different locks* and two threads can run in parallel; one object's lock does not block the other.

Comment: @MAnouti-- Thanks but who creates that class object. Is it something managed by JVM during class loading ? if i'm not wrong, we are not creating the class object for static methods

Comment: "Created by the JVM during class loading" is correct.  The programmer does not manage or create a class lock, it's done for you.

Comment: @markspace: I’m not seeing multiple questions here, it’s just that OP doesn’t know what static synchronized means. I think the duplicate target addresses the question. The class is created by the class loader.